# PHP Regex: Matching Ands - & and &amp;

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to matching and characters from html. There are three types of ands:

```
and, &, &amp;
```

I'm using the following code:

```
(&|&amp;|\band\b)
```

The problem with above code is: it also matches words which start with &

```
i.e. &copy; &euro;
```

I've also tried the following, but it does not match & character from the start and end of line in the text.

```
(\s&\s|&amp;|\band\b)
```

Comment: Is it a truth that in the case of the sole "&" that is always preceded and followed by a space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
(&amp;)|&(?!\w)|\band\b
```

Matches `and`, `&`, `&amp;`

Does not match `&copy;` `&euro;`

The middle one matches an ampersand that is not followed by a word character (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`)

Answer (score 1):

```
(&|&amp;|\band\b)
```

is a good start. Go on by reducing the result set, you will have to specify details when *not* to match. There is no magic delimiter that tells a regex what you want. So the question is: how can you tell the '&' you want to accept from those you do *not* want to accept ?

Maybe you want to accept all '&' if *not* starting a word ? So:

```
(&[^a-zA-Z]|&amp;|\band\b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :

```
$regex = '/\b((\&(amp;)?)|(and))\b/i';
```