# PHP Unable to do complete regex

Tags: php, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to run

```
$var = "Guru & Hari - Priya";
if(preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9& -]+$/', $var)){
    echo "Hi";
}else{
    echo "bye";
}
```

Somehow code is unable to understand "&".

Per regex101.com above code is fine.

Please share why PHP is unable to recogonise &

Comment: I tried it in PHP and it outputs `Hi`. What's your expected result?

Comment: It does work as expected if the string really contains just `&`. You need to verify your assumptions.

Comment: @mario it worked for these strings: `&`, `a`, `Guru & Hari - Priya`, etc. What's wrong in this? The regex search for one or more char of `A-Za-z0-9& -` due to the `+` outside the `[]`

Comment: It should output Hi, but I am getting bye. In my case somehow the code is not able to detect &. Tried using escape chars too, but logic is not working. Any workaround that you can suggest

Comment: Issue was & was getting coverted to amp;

Answer (score 1):

[not-an-answer](/questions/tagged/not-an-answer)

- You should mention/consider your string source.
- What you see as `&` is probably `&amp;` in your text value.
- The browser rendition is not always an exact representation of your data.

See also: [PHP Regex: Matching Ands - & and &amp;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768004/php-regex-matching-ands-and-amp)